# What is the equivalent to Microsoft Help Viewer in Visual Studio 2012?

Tags: visual-studio-2012, help-viewer

I'd like to create a help viewer like the one available on Visual Studio 2010 called [Microsoft Help Viewer](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Microsoft_Help_Viewer) according to Wikipedia, what is its equivalent on Visual Studio 2012 as it seen to be not available?

Comment: A program called "Microsoft Help Viewer" is the alternative.  Updated to version 2 for VS2012 and much improved.

Answer (score 0):

There is a Help Viewer that comes with Visual studio 2012.
Visual Studio uses Help Viewer 2.0.

You can open the help viewer by pressing ctrl+F1 when using vs.